# Using less with iPads / iPhones

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I just trying to use less instead of css. I'm using less.js in my webpage.
 Everything works fine but something seems to be wrong when I load the website in iPad, iPhone. I'm using bootstrap3 as my framework.

Is there something that can be done to make the less files work on iPad, iPhones? I've not used sass is that a better solution?

Comment: Less generates standard css. Can you post a screenshot and your code ?

Comment: See [Browser Support](http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a LESS app to generate CSS from your LESS code. You then include the generated CSS on your website.

On Mac OSX and Windows you can use the [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) app.

Comment: Thanks. I use `less.js` ans  `stylesheet.less`. How do I generate css out of the less files?